# Query if user has community access?

Tags: apex, soql, community

I want to implement the selfreg Napili community form of salesforce 
for that I want to add a step 
"If User has a user than to redirect to the 'forgot password' page"

So I need a step to ask something like 
If User In (Select id, name from Communitymembers where Community name = MyCommunity)

can u advise on best practice on doing so?

Thanks in advance! 
Idan Touito

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If user's profile is added as member in community then you can query result on object "NetworkMember" where NetworkId field is community id.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm